# Dependabot is not completely updating package-lock.json

Tags: npm, package-lock.json, dependabot

I'm using dependabot to update npm packages in a project.

Dependabot seems to be working okay. However I've noticed that regenerating my `package-lock.json` file every few weeks produces many package updates. By "regenerate", I mean deleting `package-lock.json` and recreating it via `npm install`.

A few questions:

- Is dependabot not updating my `package-lock.json` correctly or are these regeneration updates expected?
- If not expected, do I have dependabot misconfigured? Here is my config which seems standard:

```
- package-ecosystem: npm
  directory: /
  schedule:
    interval: weekly
```

Perhaps setting `versioning-strategy=increase` would help (see [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#versioning-strategy)). Looks like it defaults to `auto` which may mean packages aren't always updated.

Or maybe this is a dependabot bug that I should file an issue for?